# Is there a way of showing LESS CSS code (.less) in Firebug?

Tags: css, firebug, less

I've been using [LESS CSS](http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/) and I find it great. The only drawback is that the code is not shown on firebug's inspector.

IS there a way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LESS generates a  element after the CSS transformation occurs, so you're able to check elements attributes at firebug.

Comment: I'm curious about this answer as well.  I am using LESS and I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  [Here's a pretty up-to-date list of Firebug plugins](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions).

You can always write one?  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!**
Just click on the CSS tab (inside firebug) and select the inline stylesheet to see the CSS LESS CSS generated.
It is not visible in inspector tab, but in CSS tab which is better because it is optimized to inspect CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Not for less, however, there is one for **[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)** (another css compiler) called [firesass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/)
which does exactly what you'd expect.

See [this blogpost](http://nex-3.com/posts/92-firesass-bridges-the-gap-between-sass-and-firebug) for more info.